# How can I convert my tile coordinates on a 2D game into pixel coordinates in c++

Tags: c++, coordinates, pixel, tile, coordinate-transformation

I'm working on a tower defense game using c++ and SDL. I want my enemies to start on the path but every level the start is in a different spot. I could hard code the pixels but that could look a little messy at figuring out exactly where the enemies are spawning during testing and progressing the game.  The way I'm doing it is a little redundant on my part and I will tweak it up a bit. But I'm curious if there is a better way to do it than what I'm doing.

In my Tile class I have two static functions that I call when I need to convert the tile coordinates to pixel coordinates.

```
static int ConvertTileToPixelX(int tileX, int tileSize, int scale) { return tileX * tileSize * scale; }
static int ConvertTileToPixelY(int tileY, int tileSize, int scale) { return tileY * tileSize * scale; }
```

As you can see the function is the same thing, multiplying the 3 parameters together.  I can make it into one function, but for readability when I'm calling these functions makes it easier.  Now since these are static functions I can't access the variables that I have for the tiles (which contains scale and tilesize) and that's why I set them as a parameter. Now everytime I call these functions when creating an enemy I have to type this:

```
enemy(Tile::ConvertTileToPixelX(0, TILEWIDTH, SCALE), Tile::ConvertTileToPixelY(12, TILEHEIGHT, SCALE), ...)
```

As you can see it looks all funky lol. I was going for something like this:

```
enemy(Tile::ConvertTileToPixelCoords(0, 12), ...)
```

Note: I'm creating the enemy in the constructor (initialization list).

Is there a much easier way to achieve what I'm doing? Am I overthinking?

Comment: If TILEWIDTH and SCALE never change, just make them static so that you can access them in your static functions. (Possibly move them to a seperate 'GameSettings' static class perhaps?)

Comment: If you want to be really hardcore, define distinct TileCoord and PixelCoord types (encapsulating a pair of x & y values), and define type conversion operators to do the necessary arithmetic.  Then you can write function(TileCoord(2,4)) or function(PixelCoord(128,256)) as you please and let the compiler work out how to call a function(const PixelCoord&).

Comment: @BlueBoy The reason I didn't make those variables static is because I'm also creating a framework as I'm progressing in this progress. Basically When I create a game I pass in the SCALE, ect. That way If I decide to make another game; I can reuse most of my code (that I will put into a library).

Comment: @timday That actually helped. I just created a struct that stores int x and int y. Then created a static function to do the calculation returning a struct of TilePos. And when I create an enemy now, instead of giving it two values of position x and position y, I just pass it a TilePos (which is the struct containing both x and y).

Answer (score 0):

Typically code uses a matrix to store a linear transformation.

Have two types; a `TileLoc` and a `PixelLoc`.  They store both `x` and `y`.

Define `Tile2Pixel` as a type that when `*` with a `TileLoc` returns a `PixelLoc`, and `Pixel2Tile` that does the opposite.  Similarly, `TileLoc/Tike2Pixel=PixelLoc`.

It holds the scale/width/height info.

`enemy`s take a `PixelLoc`, not an x and y.

```
enemy(TileLoc{0,12}*m_TileToPixel)
```

constructs an enemy.

`Tile2Pixel` *could* use a matrix.  Or maybe not worth it.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with matrix's but I'll definitely look into it into the future.